# Is Offer the right type for a site with company share price information?

Tags: schema.org

I'm adding some structured data to a site I’m working on, and have been through the various categories on Schema.org. The site gives company share price information, and have narrowed down [`Offer`](http://schema.org/Offer) as a best fit for this type of information.

I’ve had a look to see if I can see the structured data markup on the likes of Yahoo Finance to give a clue, but can’t seem to locate the tags.

Would the general webmaster community agree that `Offer` is the best fit, or can someone else suggest something better suited?

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer, I've never used share price, but I use Organization, Place, & Offer frequently.

Based on past usage of exitpoint Offer: I'm not sure it is the best fit. Offer is meant to "sell" as a Organization > (optional POS) > Place > (optional service/product/thing) > (optional reviewed entity) > Offer, whereas stock price is more like a "organization attribute" for an upper layer. True you are "selling parts of the company" but its not a tangible asset or a service that a company can sell like a service/product/entity is. No company is in business to sell parts of itself, ya know?

That being said, if it were me, I would approach thing as a thing - those are meant to be general enough to be injected as Organization in an upper layer of RDF.

If you are using this for a big company, get more info before blindy expirimenting. RDF errors can stick for 8+ months. I specc'd a couple traders, no RDF appears for share price. This could imply that engines hold them aside, preferring to use their own trade lookups. I havent seen any, but if you can find rich SERPS of any page in any major search engine that can display trade price/history, that would be the place to crawl using the Google Rich Snippet test.

Comment: @ThePHPUnicorn, this makes sense. Offer might have the same structure as you want, however its contextually incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick walk-around on schema.org. It looks like the perfect spec. for your purposes. The only other that may fit is Thing> Product> Offer where the product is stock.

You can create an example of each and use the Google Rich Snippet Tool to test how each works and if you like the results.

```
http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets
```

Comment: But is the OP really *offering* here? ("An offer to transfer some rights to an item or to provide a service")

Comment: Good point. They are not selling anything. However, this is just a markup and there is no contract, actual offer, or consequence for choosing the closest markup that fits the scenario. It may be that they would be better off using schema.org extensions. This may be the best answer. JIC